# Telnet successful or not?

Tags: telnet

I telnet to server xxx.xxx.xxx.yyy 1433 and it can telnet into the sql server box with black screen and cursor.After cursor blinking a while, the window dialog switch back to Administrator cmd.

What is this indicates?

Comment: i think not successful not sure

Comment: any way to confirm the telnet is successful?

Answer (score 2):

Two problems here.

One is, unless your target is set to expect Telnet (terminal unencrypted) traffic on port 1433, it's not going to handshake, and your Telnet command will time out.

Two, if your NETWORK isn't configured to allow traffic on port 1433 across the firewalls (in both directions) then the handshake will fail, and your Telnet command will time out.

A further concern is this:  Port 1433 is a commonly-used SQL port, so it's well-documented as a vulnerable port for SQL injection techniques, worm infections, and so on.  So there's a VERY good chance that connections on port 1433 are not allowed, except perhaps to trusted hosts, if at all.

So unless you're probing servers to ensure that 1433 is closed, expect the IT security staff to ask some very pointed questions as to *why* you're wanting to connect via Telnet on this port.